# How can I claim an anonymous edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, anonymous-user

I made an edit to an answer without realizing that I was not logged in.

Is there a way to claim that anonymous edit so that I get credit for it?

Comment: Except your name being in the edit history what other credit did you expect?

Comment: Good point, @rene. Dionys has >2k reputation, and thus [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), so there's no reputation to be gained by having a suggested edit approved. More than credit, though, I'd say the benefit is not wasting the time of 2 reviewers.

Comment: @rene I did not know that, I just wanted my name and reputation to be displayed to give credits to my edition. Not big of a deal really, I am merely asking to point out something that might be missing. (imo, not worth a feature request).

Comment: If you had realized before the edit was peer-reviewed, you could have reviewed and "improved the edit" to approve it directly, "claiming" it in the process and taking your edit out of the review queue.

Comment: ~That is what I ended up doing @yivi. You need 2 reviewers to accept the edition so it is still in the queue ;-)~
Sorry miss red you comment. I had nothing more to improve so I discarded this option. I only approved the edit.

Comment: Ah, [it has been approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26178906). The only way I was able to find that was by you saying that you had approved it. (Apparently we don't have tools to look up edits by anonymous users.) @yivi's suggestion is actually a good one. Note that, in order for it to work, you need to "Improve" the edit, not just "Approve" it. Improving, of course, requires that you can further improve your own edit, which may be challenging.

Comment: Nice! Now that it is approved, it is a "Community" edit. I like that :)
(thanks @CodyGray, I assume you approved it)

Comment: I did not. Another user approved it. You should be able to see that on [the page I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26178906), in the box at the top. I *could* have approved it, had I been able to find it earlier. I guess I also could have *rejected* it, thus allowing you to resubmit with this account.  So many options! :-)

Comment: I think leaving it as a Community edition is for the best. Thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is no way to "claim" a pending suggested edit submitted by an anonymous user.

Not only does the tooling simply not exist, but it will probably never be implemented, as it would be ripe for abuse.

However, if the edit makes a substantive improvement to the post, then it will be approved and we will all benefit. You'll have to gratify yourself with that this time, rather than the imaginary Internet points. :-)

If you have [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), you aren't going to get any reputation from having the edit approved anyway. And having full edit privileges does give you another possible workaround, as [suggested by yivi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397601/how-to-claim-anonymous-edit#comment771201_397601): find the suggested edit you submitted as an anonymous user, and click the "Improve" button. Approval requires at least 2 users (if the vote is unanimous in favor of approving), but by improving the edit, you can force it through using your account's earned editing privileges. Note that this requires you to find something more that can be improved, on top of the improvements you already made, which may be challenging, depending on how thorough you are. A notable advantage of this is that it saves other reviewers from having to review something that you had full privileges to submit in the first place. A notable disadvantage of this is that it *may technically* be breaking [our multiple accounts rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685), namely that you should not use multiple accounts to do things that you could not do with a single account. But if you genuinely use this on rare occasion to correct an honest mistake, it's very unlikely that you will ever catch the attention or ire of a moderator.